# как правильно получить и обработать ответ от ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Не могу понять как правильно реализовать. Допустим у меня есть масив data, который включает в себя список определенных id div'ов на странице и он передается ajax на файл обработчик:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify(arr);
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://tts.cc:82/obrabotka.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {data}
});
```

На стороне обработчика через php разбирается этот массив и с каждым id div'a выполняются определенные операции в конце выдавая ответ true или false.

И нужно по мере прохода по этому массиву как-то отдавать ответ на основную страницу и если отдается true - искать div с этим id и менять его содержимое например на Hello World! Есть ли какие-то такие возможности?

Comment: То есть вам нужен ответ для каждого отдельного дива?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете собрать результаты обработки вашего массива в таком виде: id => true. Например у вас мог бы получится вот такой массив на сервере:

```
[
'div_1' => true,
'div_2' => true,
'div_3' => false
]
```

Затем верните данный результат в виде json на frontend, используя функцию json_encode.
На клиенте в функции success обойдите данный json используя for..in, проверьте каждый ключ полученного объекта и если он true, то смените значение div'а по указанному id (div_1, 2 и т.д.).

Это вариант для случая "обработать и получить все разом". Если же вам нужно на каждой итерации возвращать некий результат обработки с сервера, вам стоит смотреть в сторону технологий WebSocket или Long Polling

Answer (score 0):

Технология **AJAX** предполагает сценарий работы: *вы серверу запрос - сервер вам ответ.*
Если вам надо за 1 запрос отправить данные по всем элементам и отдавать результат обработки сервером по каждому элементу "на лету", тогда вам надо смотреть в сторону таких технологий как: **WebSockets**, **Long Polling** и пр.